# Can't include a directory in my newbie Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Simply I am trying to get ImageMagick headings into my newbie make scheme. Why is it still giving me 'no such file or directory' error?

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/ 

all: go

go: demo.o
    g++ demo.o -o test

demo.o: demo.cpp
    g++ -C demo.cpp

cleanup:
    rm *.o
```

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the flags but you have not included the variable in the compile step.  Change your makefile to this

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/ 

all: go

go: demo.o
    $(CC) demo.o -o test

demo.o: demo.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) demo.cpp

cleanup:
    rm *.o
    rm test
```

Comment: you added CCFLAGS, he defined CFLAGS

Comment: Ok, I thought those variables were automatically used. That makes a lot of sense now and fixes some of my future problems too.